# spring boot + apache CXF

Tags: apache, spring-boot, java-8, cxf

I am having application with spring boot(1.4.3) and apache cxf(3.19) and Java (8), this goes to make the request to wsdl url.

I am created wsdl client using apache cxf(3.19) and tomcat runtime as 7. Same client pasted into spring boot app. when i try to run the application it throws following exception.

```
20:49:26.262 [main] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension - **Could not load optional extension org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.wsdl11.JMSWSDLExtensionLoader

org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not create object of extension class org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.wsdl11.JMSWSDLExtensionLoader.**
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.load(Extension.java:240)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.loadAndRegister(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:217)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.getBeansOfType(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:350)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.setBus(WSDLManagerImpl.java:137)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector.invokeSetter(ResourceInjector.java:287)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector.visitMethod(ResourceInjector.java:232)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.annotation.AnnotationProcessor.processMethods(AnnotationProcessor.java:89)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.annotation.AnnotationProcessor.accept(AnnotationProcessor.java:72)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:118)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:112)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.loadAndRegister(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:246)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.getBeanOfType(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusImpl.getExtension(CXFBusImpl.java:107)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:170)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initialize(ServiceImpl.java:161)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:82)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)
    at com.test.servicesimplservice.ServIcesimPlservicE.<init>(ServIcesimPlservicE.java:43)
    at **com.test.servicesimplservice.ServIcesimPlservicE_Client.main(ServIcesimPlservicEPort_Client.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.wsdl.JAXBExtensionHelper.addExtensions(Ljavax/wsdl/extensions/ExtensionRegistry;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)V**
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.wsdl11.JMSWSDLExtensionLoader.addExtensions(JMSWSDLExtensionLoader.java:67)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.wsdl11.JMSWSDLExtensionLoader.<init>(JMSWSDLExtensionLoader.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.load(Extension.java:217)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

Please help me to resolve the issue

Comment: Is the tomcat spring-boot embedded or external one?

Comment: Using embedded tomcat and version of 8.5.4

Comment: can you make sure you are using the same version of apache cxf (i.e. using mvn dependecy:tree) ?